# How to quote programming code in AP Style?

Tags: style, technical-writing, journalism, ap-style, programming

I would like to put the following code in an article that is written in AP Style:

```
puts 'Hello, world!'
```

How do I do this? If I were to put the code (C++, Ruby, whatever) in an article that was written in a newspaper, how would I write it? Is the entire thing surrounded by quotes, brackets, etc? How do you deal with line breaks?

I didn't find any help in [this guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465082998).

Comment: I think that's up to the publication editor. It's a formatting question, and is governed by house rules, not AP style.

Comment: Why don't you look in the AP Stylebook? I'm sure any university library will have a copy or online subscription.

Comment: @what I own [this](https://www.amazon.com/Associated-Press-Stylebook-Briefing-Media/dp/0465082998/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1480708022&sr=8-1&keywords=9780465082995) and have looked in it pretty thoroughly...

Comment: That's good, because then you know that they don't prescribe how you quote programming code, and that is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is specifically covered by AP style. My personal approach would be to present the code in a block quote. (Or, if it's something really short, just a different font face.) But you're not going to find a "rule" that everybody follows for this situation. It's really up to the individual publisher.